# Pasar un array al controller de laravel mediante AJAX

Tags: laravel, ajax, array

Hola buenas pues estoy intentando pasar mediante ajax un array al controller de laravel pero me esta dando problema con el método post, a ver si con un poco de ayuda entre todos podemos sacarlo, mucha gracias de ante mano.

***PD: El array lo monto a partir de los ids que muestra el filtro de datatable, pero lo convierto a array, no creo que tenga ahi el problema...***

**Consulta AJAX**

```
var array=$("#albaran-table").DataTable().rows({filter: 'applied'}).data().map(a => a.id).toArray();
    
    var ruta = '{{ route("gastos.unicos") }}';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ruta, 
        data:array,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data) {
            console.log("en el jquery");
            if (data.success == 'incidencias hecho') {
                alert('hechos');
            }
            //errores
            if (data.errors != "" && data.errors != null) {
            }
        }
    })
```

**Route**

```
    Route::post('/albaran/gastos/unicos', 'AlbaranController@gastos_unicos')->name('gastos.unicos');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function gastos_unicos(Request $request)
{
    Log::info($request);
    Log::info('GASTOS UNICOS');
}
```

Comment: Cual es el error que te muestra?, cuando es una peticion post tiene que mandar el token de laravel, no lo veo declarado, esta dentrode un array?

Comment: @Juan Rivera lo probe tambien y el error que me sale en el navegador es error POST 419

Comment: @Gerardo me parece que es lo del token siempre se me olvida maldita sea jejejej

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/413394/edit) tu pregunta y coloca el error ahi

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin como introduzco el token en este caso?

Comment: @Juan Rivera asi?   data:array'&_token='+"{{ csrf_token() }}",

Comment: Puede de esta forma
data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", "array": +array },

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a los dos ya esta on lo ultimo de gerardo

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin  te dije ayer que si que me pasaba el array bien siempre y cuando el array fuese de solo 1 elemento cuanto intento mandar varios elementos dentro de la matriz el controller me lo devuelve como NAN mmm eso a que puede deverse?

Answer (score 2):

Bueno chicos para los que han seguido la pregunta y para los que han respondido muchas gracias, para solucionar mi error deje el ajax tal cual esta aqui,

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: ruta, 
        data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", array },
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data) {
            console.log("en el jquery");
            if (data.success == 'incidencias hecho') {
                alert('hechos');
            }
            //errores
            if (data.errors != "" && data.errors != null) {
            }
        }
    })
```